# Generating a random string of fixed length where certain values are prohibited

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

In Python 2.7, how do I most efficiently produce a unique, random string of `len=3` - formed only of digits - where values contained in a list (called `exclude_me`) are *not considered* while the random string is being calculated?

E.g. `exclude_me=['312','534','434','999',...........,'123']`

Comment: What is the desired range of your random numbers?

Comment: You can't know if the random string is in the banned list until the string is completely assembled.  If you manipulate only the final digit to avoid generating a banned value, that seems like it would skew your results.  It might be best to just keep generating random values until you get one that passes.

Comment: Is the initial setup important with regard to performance, or will you be picking lots of random strings once set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exclusion list is short, repeating a random choice until the result is not excluded will be the most efficient approach:

```
excluded = set(int(x) for x in exclude_me)

while True:
    candidate = random.randint(0, 999)
    if candidate not in excluded:
        result_int = candidate
        break

result = '{:03d}'.format(result_int)
```

If, on the other hand, the exclusion list is long, you can avoid looping over many iterations by preparing the set of eligible values:

```
included = set(range(1000)) - excluded
result_int = random.choice(list(included))
```

Answer (score 1):

A there are only 1000 numbers, you may as well just make a list of them without the excluded ones and then choose randomly from that:

```
import random

numbers = range (111,1000)
exclude_me = [313,534,434,999,123]
difference = set(numbers).difference(set(exclude_me))
candidates = list(difference)
str(random.choice(candidates))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the `exclude_me` list is to prevent duplicate numbers by storing those that have already been generated, you can create an initial list of valid numbers, randomly shuffle the list, then pop an item whenever you need one. This way you don't need a parallel list to keep track those values that have already been generated, and most of the work is in the initial setup.

```
import random

population = ['{:03d}'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
random.shuffle(population)

# get 10 unique numbers
for i in range(10):
    print(population.pop())
```

This sort of thing is viable for 1000 numbers. Perhaps not so good for very large lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a fixed list of approximately 1000 strings (i.e. `['000', '001', ..., '999']`, omitting whatever values you like, then call `random.choice()` on that list.

If you don't want to type 1000 strings, you could programatically generate the list using something like `range()` and then `.remove()` your banned values.

Answer (score -1):

A very easy (though not very efficient) way to do this:

```
import random

digits = '0123456789'
blacklist = set(['312','534','434','999',...........,'123'])

answer = '312'
while answer in blacklist:
    answer = ''.join([str(i) for i in (random.choice(digits) for _ in range(3))])
```

Another similarly inefficient way:

```
import itertools
import random

digits = '0123456789'
blacklist = set(['312','534','434','999',...........,'123'])

options = [i for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(digits, 3) if i not in blacklist]
answer = random.choice(options)
```

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for, but `random.sample(digits*3)` won't have even distribution of digits. For example '111' should have 1-in-1000 chance of occurring from an even distribution, but the sample from a long string will give you `(3/30) * (2/29) * (1/28) = 0.0002463`